# How to compile C++ program with a main, header and implementation file using command prompt, notepad and MinGW?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am trying to learn C++ myself. I have installed minGW in my computer and to compile any .cpp file I use the command g++ -o main main.cpp in command prompt to compile and then I type main.exe to run it and it usually works. I use notepad to write .cpp files by the away. But when I tried to compile programs with separate header file (test.h for example) and implementation file ( test.cpp for example) it does not compile. I typed the code g++ main.cpp test.cpp in the command prompt but it showed me error. I am not sure if the code I typed in the command prompt is right but I found it on this pdf file. [link to the pdf file](http://math.uaa.alaska.edu/~afkjm/csce211/handouts/SeparateCompilation.pdf)

I typed exactly the 1st code given on the pdf file. For convenient the code is given below:

File: Num.h

```
class Num{
private:
 int num;
 public:
 Num(int n);
 int getNum();
};
```

File: Num.cpp

```
#include "Num.h"
Num::Num() : num(0) { }
Num::Num(int n): num(n) {}
int Num::getNum()
{
 return num;
}
```

File: main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Num.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 Num n(35);
 cout << n.getNum() << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

And to compile this from the command prompt I typed

```
g++ main.cpp Num.cpp
```

But the cmd shows the error massage "`no declaration matches 'Num::Num()'`".

As I am new to this I don't know what to do or what is wrong with this code. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your bug is in your  `Num.h` header. You declared `Num(int n);` but did not declare `Num()` closing as a typo. Your compiler told you that but I expect you did not understand its message.

Answer (score 0):

You header doesn't include your zero arg constructor.

try

```
class Num{
private:
 int num;
 public:
 Num();  //added this
 Num(int n);
 int getNum();
};
```

Comment: Thank you sir, your reply was very helpful. But would the previous code work in code block? I was following a youtube video where the youtuber used code block and didn't use zero arg constructor but it worked and mine didn't. That's why asking.

Comment: The problem is in Num.cpp where you attempt to defined the zero arg ctor (short for constructor) without it having been declared in the header. You either need to remove the definition or add the declaration. I am not sure which compiler this youtube video was using, but it is non-standard behavior.